Chromecasting video calls onto Android television screens
I want to know whether there is a way to screencast/Chromecast video (such as video, from WhatsApp, phone/video calls), onto an Android television screen.

Assuming the Android TV is not physically connected to the device/dongle, streaming via Chromecast usually requires support from the app as the TV receiver will want to get the video stream from either the device or a cloud server using a supported protocol. The big problem is that the microphone input would be separate from a usual play video stream. If the device is HDMI to TV and has micrphone/webcam then it is possible as seen here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/1b0ih7w/will_video_calling_work_on_chromecast_with_google/ More details about the configuration may help.
